# How to click hypertext link in aspx site with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, asp.net, eclipse, html-table, htmlunit

I'm working on an apsx website. I can't find a way to click on a link inside a table with HtmlUnit.
I've already tried alot of ways but I get an "ItemNotFound" exception or "NullPointerException".

Here's my code:

```
public static void selezionaConto(HtmlPage page, int nConto) throws Exception {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) 
    {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        final HtmlPage currentPage = page; 

        nConto = 5;

        switch (nConto) {   
            case 1:

                break;

            case 2:

                break;

            case 3:

                break;

            case 4:

                break;

            case 5:

                HtmlAnchor nextLink = currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//a[@id='lnkQuintoConto']");
                HtmlPage newPage = nextLink.click();
                System.out.println(newPage.asXml());

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide your complete case (with URL), so others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I find difficulty to add images of the HTML code since I don't have enough reputation. Can't give you the URL since it involves to gives sensible informations, but I'm advancing figuring out what my problem exactly is:
When I look for a particular href in the code the program can't find it and that's because it seems to not be part of the HTML code at all.
I've noticed that by printing at screen all the code detected by asXml() method. It shows just the initial part of the code and then end it with </html> even if the original code don't have that tag in that point but at the end.

Comment: Your XPath seems to be incorrect, you can use something like `"//div[@id='navGoButton']"`, or post your HTML/XML which is relevant to that button

Comment: If you can tell me how to get 2 more reputations point I can put the images of the code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot :)
I've edited main post with images of the HTML. The href I need to reach is the highlighted one

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
        currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='SelezDecretoButton']");
```

or

```
        currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//a[@id='lnkQuintoConto']");
```

or

```
        currentPage.getAnchorByHref(complere_href)
```

XPath means: from root `//`, select recursively in children, `a` with `@id` or `@class` attribute of `whatever`.

Comment: I've edit code in main post.
Now i got this exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you post the value of `currentPage.asXml()`? That's what HtmlUnit sees

Comment: Sorry had to post it in a different answer cause it's pretty long! :)

Comment: Since i didn't post the whole HTML in the main post, what asXml() gives me is all the source's HTML code until the green text. What's after the green text is not displayed.